# Python : Iterate a dataframe including type of file and url to download files

Tags: python, pandas, url, download

I've a dataframe as below -

| type | url |
| --- | --- |
| **Cov** | **link1.ndjson** |
| Cov | link2.ndjson |
| EOB | link1.ndjson |
| Patient | link1.ndjson |

There are N number of rows with links for three types of files. Now, as a new-bie in Python, I use the type of file and it's link one by one to download the files.

I can download the files now manually using code

```
import requests
url='https://fakesite.com/4472/link1.ndjson' #the link is from first row of above dataframe
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' %access_token,
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
    
import sys
original_stdout = sys.stdout # Save a reference to the original standard output
with open('Cov_link1.ndjson', 'w') as f:
    #file is concatenation of first row of dataframe type+_+url
    sys.stdout = f # Change the standard output to the file we created.
    print(response.text)
    sys.stdout = original_stdout # Reset the standard output to its original value
```

The request is to download files i.e all the N number of rows in dataframe. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if this serves your purpose:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['Cov','Cov','EOB','Patient'], 'url':['link1.ndjson','link2.ndjson','link1.ndjson','link1.ndjson']})
df['name'] = df['type'] + '_' + df['url']

url_list = list(df['url'])
name_list = list(df['name'])

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' %access_token,
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
}

result = list(zip(url_list,name_list))
for i,j in result:
    url_list ='url' + i
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    original_stdout = sys.stdout
    
    with open(j, 'w') as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        print(response.text)
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
```

Comment: Hi Kartik, all the urls should be taken directly from the df's column. Can we use iterrows/tuple to grab them as indexes and use in for loop below?

Comment: When I used something like

for index, row in df.iterrows():
#print(row['type'], row['url'])
df['name'] = df['type'] + '_' + df['url']


The code isn't responding at all. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: df.iterrows worked, but can we have one for loop for both url_list and name_list? The response,text has to be printed in a file as soon as we grab a url for a particular file.

Comment: `for i,j in map(None,url_list,name_list):
    url_list ='https://api.fakesite.com/data/4472/' + i
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    original_stdout = sys.stdout
    with open(j, 'w') as f:
        sys.stdout = f
        print(response.text)
        sys.stdout = original_stdou` Neither zip, longestzip and MAP are working.

Comment: Also, I want the file name to be downloaded to be COV_file1.ndjson (the link1 being https://api.fakesite.com/data/4472/file1.ndjson), COV_file2.ndjson(the link2 being https://api.fakesite.com/data/4472/file2.ndjson).

Comment: Can you check if the latest edited answer serve your purpose.